# Refreshing Port Namein combobox - WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, port

I have a combobox to which I binded available port names:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type ports:SerialPort}" MethodName="GetPortNames" x:Key="portNames"/>

           <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="21" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource portNames}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static ConnectionMngr.Instance}, Path=PortSettings.PortName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

If I open the window when the COM is connected, then I see the port name value in the combobox.

If I open the window when the COM is not connected, I do not see the value in the combobox, but I want that when I connect the COM the value will be there.

How can I cause refershing the combobox when the COM is connected to see the value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the class used as instance you bind to, implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise it in the property you want updated

```
public string PortName 
{ 
    get { return __portName;}
    set
      {
          if_portName == value) return;
          _portName = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("PortName");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks,Already implemented. the thing is that the portname property is not set to any value. I want to refresh the items in the combobox. The items in the combobox are the available ports in the operaing system. if no port is available and now I insert a usb there is a new COM in the operating system. I want that the combobox will then refresh itself to have the new COM as item. thanks